How to send/receive mail in ThunderBird?
I reinstalled Postfix in DigitalOcean. Following this: install postfix
After that, i added some users. And I tried to access this user's mail account to ThunderBird. But I couldn't access it directly, that's why I tried to access it manually. After accessing it, I couldn't send or receive mail from another user. I also can not send or receive from Gmail accounts. This is main.cf:
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 3.6 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 3.6



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 4
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
debug_peer_list = problem.domain

To solve this problem i followed some solutions like "Install and configure a mail server with Postfix, Dovecot, and Mozilla Thunderbird on Debian" youtube in youtube. In this video, I installed apt install dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d. I can send/receive mails in DigitalOcean console. Also, before this problem i could send/receive mails in ThunderBird between users but i couldn't send/receive mails to Gmail accounts also. As a result how can i solve this problem? Should i configure postfix (main.cf)? How can i solve this problem?
